# How to load terms of a custom taxonomy of a product in woocommerce cart page

Tags: categories, custom-taxonomy, woocommerce-offtopic

I have created a custom taxonomy called "job_orders" to a products in woocommerce. I want to edit cart page and show then terms of job_orders inside cart table. currently I'm using the below script which echo all the terms , I want to show only the categories select in back end.I appreciate if anybody can help on this.

```
$terms = get_terms('job_orders','hide-empty=0&orderby=id');
//shuffle($terms);   // dlete this line if you don't want it random.
$sep = '';
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    if( ++$count > 60 ) break;   // number of tags here.
    //echo $sep . ''.$term->name.'';
    echo $sep . $term->name;
    $sep = ', ';  // Put your separator here.
}
```

Above goes inside below woocommerce loop in cart.php

```
foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the code that do the trick

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $product_id, 'my_taxo' );
foreach ($terms as $term) {
$product_cat = $term->name;
}
echo $product_cat ;
```

from below discussion
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33495716/get-the-product-categories-and-display-it-on-cart-page-woocommerce
Thanks for the authors